# how to publish web service on internet

Tags: web-server, asp.net, internet, windows, intranet

I developed web-services in c# and published on IIS

now i want to take this web-services out of Intranet to Internet i am looking for what are possible solutions for this.

I am very much beginner to this.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are hosting it at your home and you will probably have a dynamic ip address from your ISP.

So first you need a fixed IP. Dyndns.com is a free service that maps a hostname (yourhostname.dyndns.org) to an (dynamic) ip address. It also has a client that updates the mapping to the dynamic ip address automatically.

Secondly you will have to get your local address of you ISS server/computer fixed, this can be done at the network adapters screen at your configuration panel.

Then you have to open the port needed on your router, this is depending on how your bindings are on your ISS server.

If you are using a local firewall you might need to configure that one.

Then you should be able to surf to the hostname you requested at dyndns from a remote computer and get your website.

Cheers

Comment: thank you very much for steps and will definetely check Dyndns.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner with this, find some hosting provider that gives what you need and put your server there. You'll also want to register a domain and point it to your site, your hosting provider will tell you how to do that.

If you want to set it up in the intranet, you need to:

- Setup it in a server properly configured. Can be tricky.
- Configure a NAT redirect in your router so when someone connects to a(some) specific port(s) of your network public address the request will be redirected at your server.
- If you need a new domain other than the one you already own, register it. Check if your IP is static(probably for a medium sized bussiness) or dynamic (home or small bussiness). If your IP is dynamic configuration is a little more complicated.