# how to publish web service on internet

Tags: windows, .net, web-services, internet, intranet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to publish web service on internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/258162/how-to-publish-web-service-on-internet)

I developed web-services in c# and published them on IIS.

Now I want to take these web-services out of Intranet and expose them on the Internet. I am  looking the possible solutions for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy a domain like somename.com and then buy a ASP.NET hosting plan. You will find many hosts by searching for "ASP.NET hosting" on Google. You will be provide a web based tool like Plesk through which you can deploy and manage your webservices.

Answer (score 0):

1 st place the web server on an Internet facing machine with its own IP address (or setup the firewall/proxy correctly).

2nd Try to connect through another network to the IP address of the web service server machine.

Voila the first step has been taken. If you've got a decent webserver running in you're business you could host the service on that machine. Use some of the other advices given to hire ASP.NET hosting if you need it.